# eclipse project properties window size is very small

Tags: eclipse-cdt

When I first open the properties window for a project, the properties window size is normal. However, if you just leave this window at for example `C/C++` `Build/ Settings` tab, next time when you open the properties window, it will be very small( of course you can resize it by mouse). I think this is very inconvenient, because sometimes tabs like tool chain version will be folded and resize it every time cost extra time. Is there any work around?

**Small properties window**

[image]

**Normal properties window**

[image]

The picture shows `TrueSTUDIO` which is a eclipse based IDE, and eclipse CDT also has this small issue.

Comment: If the issue has not yet been reported to Eclipse CDT, please report it to Eclipse CDT.

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include directly the images instead of links for the shake of clarity to the people trying to help you. 
Please check the documentation [on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Carlos thank you, I may not have the enough reputation to include images directly...

Comment: Thanks to you to join the community. I forgot the permissions issue. I would do it for you :) Hope you find an answer soon. Anyway upvoted you maybe you will get the permissions in a short time.